# How to convert java project into .exe file?

Tags: exe

i created selenium webdriver java project,is it possible to convert into .exe file.If it is possible means whether it runs in all other devices without need of any specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Launch4J java exe wrapper: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Here is the documentation: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html

Comment: After coverted exe file whether run in all systems

Comment: what `all systems` do you mean? exe files will work on Windows systems. on MacOS and Linux systems exe files are not considered as executables and cannot be launched.

Answer (score 0):

In looking for a solution to this myself I recently created an application that can generate executable launchers, with optional embedded icon, for jar files.

CStExe will compile C# scripts into Windows executables, you can write C# scripts, or edit the included example script, to launch a batch file that points to your jar files or directly launch the jar file from the C# script then use CStExe to compile the script into a Windows executable.

Personally I prefer to use the executable to launch a batch (.bat) file rather than launching the jar directly.  With this method you can just edit the batch file to reflect command/argument changes over the course of your applications development without having to re-compile the executable.

You can grab CStExe from my personal site here:
http://1337atr.weebly.com/cstexe.html

P.S.  One of the benefits of this method is that you have a few options in regards to how the end user has access to the Java Runtime Environment.

One of my favorites is that you can bundle the JRE with your application so that the end user doesn't have to install it at all.  In this case simply include the JRE in a subdirectory of your application.

For example if you have created an executable that launches a batch file that points to your jar, instead of calling java -jar from the batch file use something like "Java\JRE_1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe -jar Jars\MyApplication.jar" without quotes.  This will launch the application via the included JRE.

Conversely if you're skilled in C# you could write your C# script so that running the compiled executable will check for installed Java and if it is either not found or an incorrect version instead of trying to launch the application it launches an included JRE installer or opens a web browser to the JRE download page.